# Is there a method to fit a bound to the plot of an linear inequality?

Tags: curve-fitting, bounds, inequality, linear-programming

I have a physical dataset that is bounded by several different processes, and thus the plot takes the form of a linear inequality:

[image]

I'm specifically interested in studying the upper bound.  **Is there a method that could estimate the line that forms the upper limit of the inequality?**

You see plots of inequalities frequently in the physical sciences (*[phase diagrams](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch14/graphics/14_14fig.gif) or [Hjulström curves](https://img.geocaching.com/cache/large/c1459167-191d-4468-95c5-7adfdcfe5f42.jpg) for example*) but I'm having troubling finding the technique to estimate the boundaries.

Comment: What can you tell us about the measurement errors in the $x$ and $y$ values?  How would you assess the accuracy of the line?  After all, anyone could draw a line that is way to the right and up and all points would lie on one side of it.  We need information to determine what estimated line would be *best* in some sense.

Comment: I can easily report error in the $y$ values. It's about ±0.7 dBA. Error in the $x$ values are likely not constant (increasing with $x$), but I'd guess they're far less than $0.15 x$.